# JsonUtility.ToJson is giving nulls to all fields

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

Ok So I'm making an api to interface with AWS Cognito and I've gotten to the point where I can authentic a user and get the IdToken (etc) returned back as JSON, it looks like this:

```
{
  "AuthenticationResult": {
    "AccessToken": "eyJraWQiOiJ1aWtyV0FNajZYbllcL0tVeG10RndJb1N4U0RhMFRST3NpdWg3Z1JTcnFhWT0iLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.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.y6oG5t3Q_DB9Clv3BBhO8PtBoyiS5WolkYZyKyLGEFkkPIIenIpio-xIY7i9efcvpw89PKLy_iZT6VyGxZ1HZpK6AMiJnhMmOG191GOuyrv5lN_dm8LEkRBLyeKzQEK_5tHgfwEsu1AYLQlIaX58FAajG2XwAUXtBOCqm45ej2HpNjXgG2JOFnz0Ayb9DGkXqsYYk-qD9erAubt-xu9hyOV4WmcJ7RmQ9RlRuxvXxdorJurzriYNnM6_zaSqI54lrS4pX-TVcy082JRfenOeGuCS_Wn5L49_XBdIfDgfEqxaifI6eubXpvuKttEZxje_LQuPwfYTVNw6_MkZN7IoYQ",
    "ExpiresIn": 3600,
    "IdToken": "eyJraWQiOiJzNUpzNEtIZ2h3M1lNamVEeFNreXRPNDlIUHJDTExCbUN5blhqak56UEdBPSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.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.dn9v_J6VYi1ont7H2rj9tuIvzHXO4GL_sMaHy6SS48BF-JP-lVYs_tI_d5fUwE9pYJpiskMpVJlfGivliqsIdJkZAZrWUPiQYLSEwPQOblrVXmiXt-mwYe8w1D_jhYT9tg1aIW3pF8A7PWOF6s3-LyBhcs1I6VML8faVxB3ai2HMm3CQPq-c2GC3ad_IlhCkb9FDXESmu4B9gXjXt6xG4V-fNBSrs325gxAt95VmXGJnh0DZQPs52olwDbFPSMm5vxLwEtlmrgqG431kRK8r8E8KN_NSmmGBDBxcz3oEoy1Io8Mba8y6YmUP1LNIGLzhuFqDgnCX_NO0HVC2PPsUYw",
    "RefreshToken": "eyJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIiwiYWxnIjoiUlNBLU9BRVAifQ.UqTRq3nsMyfBVYTvFhHFtHmcW6NrMzCEB8-_Aytg_mBitYs_mSEam41iXC7htD36VlkvuTPYk7MR92Bx5jhvmOvlKsG0T9o_WRqf1EXBO8ubRaUd9IefZXh8f4cNLlnv3SHvxnN_s5D4-MppvP3ESRXS9n6TiDHVLqLFuun5JQ_K6jfDJ2Sn0mnq8rlfG6xBX0wal1Y74pzCoSbsayOm2I9CA-IiED5fbxyObnkyJOGtgX7gBa2OoIk2w4Qxr6cc6evCaDl4jKk_DFmvaoPfHhNRQWOGvu23gruyywwrWCXu-UwThKaE5cz2nfo29JqPNU85FbWvZPYVLUic_ddEIA.AfYaiVzXYCis3kBd.xHhhT0qPV9wKlDivoMTNSbZIwqLy3djtcCKXDcbYTrAQG2Qti3xGzxBlFEkYH2FrP_u7GI-mpDerae-54hjB9mU6YUZ268xqJZr1G41vjEOpbG8J0Ipa9KiB_bmq63XtCC6V6zPR_W880rlyZ9QkwwexBWBag0tH8WfLsWH7nfaNdiZuQWtEYf4KDZNar_XMXnE3sg_-by-wWtI27GYXqkkN9m1LvmEHhNUUMoe93K0IGMcWHwlQW62iLNJHgejSnx8JcvyiHilTFrKH1pfEfD_GbEtfqlH0q1_8QV8xq0gE_xUYPWHHbA5zXoxeEMltKhJ62FBJOD15LG1mP27hvupGJnz8dkWIm4QBPbIw85YG6_GT3jECkLkD6Pjm9Ph7Xbx69JGINWHzmFf1BnIzuZP6GcDbuaQPi1dfR4ucHIC5zYmol2lQ-C4kfAXrkjlHWeq4NOzAR0s1S8NNy990TVbDbb1BtjtFHtgFjk-FxGJ8c-pdLQTsubPUhnjv2JnAr5Fq8uXXiBTYm1ZnI904Uf_7rI2LM1NDe9_s5e6Fx3APy2ZyYgVHFQrGkk8Z37TRDiGn3_V1OxH78f9xZ6kjYbMqB0oo3oerhUKZjWMqJJP2MknemAndx865kU0tubfd74GVJIckEj5mZ_ChZ1nz8pR4c-fHPqo2DjOAsbR67Ty9ujZb4UOuKq1BIWWwPcMUEE1ZtOfCOxL2i-1gAwWCbPzE4ZvQ5Ky_B48zYsJTQb2yBc1c1LpkLlP3Sp8dGZOT_bCEtl-KQP_TYsTB5XkGXVTlcbqWx1abWIViLaKRg3DDecDDPGIxwHbxl9CDR1hEFPT_-mwENTVyUdfabW3P0msmxGDnEV2CRm_Rp6qC5IZCgI1rs-bnB_fG_dThwAUKPxtNbCERYWZzttYS0Lm8_zfmMeEuzki037X811kGaz0g8kj3_qnT1au8660sENL3BN4yqVbeZp6hJp1UwTIFITIzuqnhxlcMMFZ8BhtduS-NIduyzc7jmjtN-XygIKowX0l8MKLbN-n3YxsuqeFZ-kFsDJzCdNsb_gwPbCE7xUH6KiVNpHB4ZmN__-5rGLt0pwBjqsjZX-rG_ajiPX0avs3NsSLxgdBRgqqJc6iNiIoPQll-Gow17YFjHIEuj_6rWiC4WCrmtpJa7JjusC9G1rXxvmjmhpwA0pckitMp_zpiKUJIENjvTyGZ-BcBH-BBYTo7GD2B575foo1hjCgMww9e-P7sZ9N73vrcEC8wh_XEwp1zmSNlJcfd-ZEpCxTmKLDHWBzjffawbDrZoW9jusJpjs1iFmTRgIYR1l1D.7r6I2Jgnedf2Zgkfx9BHGA",
    "TokenType": "Bearer"
  },
  "ChallengeParameters": {}
}
```

I converted this to the relevant classes in C#:

```
    public class AuthenticationResult
    {
        public string AccessToken;
        public int ExpiresIn;
        public string IdToken;
        public string RefreshToken;
        public string TokenType;
    }

    public class ChallengeParameters
    {
    }

    public class Auth
    {
        public AuthenticationResult AuthenticationResult;
        public ChallengeParameters ChallengeParameters;
    }
```

I think that should match perfectly (I've already found out that Unity doesn't want any of the { get/set } type code.

```
        var r = JsonUtility.FromJson<Auth>(www.downloadHandler.text);
        Debug.Log(r);
        Debug.Log(r.AuthenticationResult);
        Debug.Log(r.AuthenticationResult.TokenType);
```

Returns:

```
[Log] [DBTest/Editor/DBTest.cs:257] [DBTest/<Login>d__11] [MoveNext] [20:50:03] MyNamespace.DBTest+Auth
[Log] [DBTest/Editor/DBTest.cs:258] [DBTest/<Login>d__11] [MoveNext] [20:50:03] Null
[Exception] [DBTest/Editor/DBTest.cs:259] [DBTest+<Login>d__11] [MoveNext] [20:50:03] NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: `r.AuthenticationResult` returns null and you can see in your output, the next line obviously then will raise exception. Inspect the string value in downloadhandler.text in your code, probably it is not having what you expect.

Comment: Shouldn't you have the `[Serializable]` attribute on your classes?

Comment: @Mihail bingo!! I knew it was something subtle and silly to forget.  If you want to resubmit this as an answer I can green check it

Answer (score 1):

When using `JsonUtility` your classes must have the attribute `[System.Serializable]`, like so:

```cs
[System.Serializable]
public class AuthenticationResult
{
    public string AccessToken;
    public int ExpiresIn;
    public string IdToken;
    public string RefreshToken;
    public string TokenType;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class ChallengeParameters
{
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Auth
{
    public AuthenticationResult AuthenticationResult;
    public ChallengeParameters ChallengeParameters;
}
```